# we will investigate and find out who did what

Tags: relative-pronouns

what does "who did what" mean in this sentence: "We will investigate and find out 'who did what'" And particularly what "what" refers to.

Comment: "Somebody did something, somebody else did something else." "Who did what?" "We will investigate and find out."

Comment: @FuadHirad By "stands for", are you asking for their meanings or their grammatical constructions?

Answer (score 1):

> what does "who did what" stands for this sentence

This is unknown.  That is why an investigation is happening.

What comes to mind is this:  A major event has taken place that consists of a number or series of smaller events.  Multiple people are suspected to have taken part in at least one or more of the smaller events, and they want to know which people did what things.